# Why does Python 2.7 calculate 3 x 2 as 33 ? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-2.7

A new learner,I am encountering a problem while defining variable b-

```
def b():
    b() 
b = a * 2
print "If you double it..."
time.sleep(3)
print "..you have",b
```

-If input for b is 3,I am getting 33 as answer for multiplication.Please tell me what am I doing wrong.Any help is appreciated

Comment: Where is `a` defined? why is there a `b()` function unneccesarily?

Comment: This isn't a meaningful code segment; there is no indication where you enter a value for `b` or `a`, and the meaning of `b` is changing from function to plain variable during the run.

Comment: Please update your code snippet

Answer (score 3):

The code originally posted, is, unfortunately, nonsense.

Python lets us define a function `b()` as `b()`, but we'll get a recursion error if we try to use it.

```
def b():
    b()

b()
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Instead of using `b`, you immediately redefine `b = a* 2`

Now if `a` is the char or string `'3'` from user input, then `'3' * 2`  being `'33'` is quite normal and to be expected.  This could be avoided by calling `a = int(a)` to convert `a` to an integer number or `a = float(a)` to convert `a` to a floating point decimal number before doing the multiplication.

We can experiment with `*` in Python's shell to see what is happening:

```
3*2
answer: 6
'3'*2
answer: '33'
```

In the first case, the integer 3 is multiplied by the integer 2, and the answer is 6.

In the second case, the character '3' is multiplied by the integer 2, and Python defines this as a string with '3' appearing twice, i.e. '33'

Similarly:

```
3*'3'
answer: '333'
```

What is happening here is called *operator overloading*.  Python calls different code that performs very different functions, all depending on what types are associated with the operator `*`.  This allows for more compact code, at the expense of more work learning as a beginner.

The multiplication of strings to repeat them is occasionally quite useful:

```
print "We wish you a Merry Christmas!\n"*3 + "And a Happy New Year!"
We wish you a Merry Christmas!
We wish you a Merry Christmas!
We wish you a Merry Christmas!
And a Happy New Year!
```